# Half life of a radioactive sample

Tags: exponential-function

> The half of thallium-$201$ is $73$ hrs. How many hours will it take for an amount of thallium-$201$ to decay so that only $5%$ of the original amount remains ?

So I decide to use this

$$0.05P=P(0.05)^{73}$$

Got confused

Comment: If the rate of decay is $r$ and the half-life is $73$ hours then $$r^{73}=\frac12$$

Comment: I don’t see a question here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A half life of $73$ hours means that after $t$ hours, what remains is
$$
0.5^{t/73}
$$
of the original substance. (Note how, for $t=73$, the exponent becomes $1$, so we are left with $0.5$ of the original substance, exactly like we are supposed to. This is a quick check to make sure we have the right expression.)

Now you want to find the value of $t$ for which $5\%$ of the original substance is left. That means that you want to solve
$$
0.05=0.5^{t/73}
$$

Comment: How did you get 0.5 as the initial amount?

Comment: @AshalleySamuel: the initial amount is irrelevant, it will cancel out. Just look at your equation, you have $P$ on both sides.

Comment: Oh i get it now. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that doesn't use $e$.

The fraction you have after $t$ years is
$$
f(t) = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{t/73}.
$$
Solve
$$
f(t) = 0.05
$$
for $t$, using logarithms or by numerical trial and error.

You can do a quick estimate by noting that 
$$
\frac{1}{2^4} =  
\frac{1}{16} > \frac{1}{20} >  
\frac{1}{32} =  \frac{1}{2^5} 
$$ 
so the answer will be beteen $4$ and $5$ periods of length $73$, probably nearer to the former -  somewhat more than $300$ years.